# Android AudioRecord clipping

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I'm trying to record some audio from the microphone using AudioRecord.
The recording works, but the volume is way to loud and I'm getting horrible clipping.
I tried to use AutomaticGainControl, but it is not available on my device.
Is there any other way to lower the volume either automatically or manually?

This is the code I'm using:

```
sampleRate = 44100
channel = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
encoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT

audioRecord =new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, //also tried VOICE_RECOGNITION
            sampleRate, channel, encoding,
            bufferSize)

audioRecord.startRecording()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I was hearing wasn't clipping caused by volume, but by wrong byte order. The clip was recorded with little-endian and I was replaying it with big-endian. Because of that lower volume values were just amplified and otherwise unaffected, since the most significant bits were all 0, but when the volume was higher, the MSB were not 0 and the overall value got corrupted into white noise.